# properties of semantic equivalence proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I would like to prove using semantic equivalences that

```
(p ⇒ q) ∧ (¬q ⇒  r) ≡ (r ⇒ p) ⇒ q
```

but I keep getting stuck at the same point. Can someone please tell me where I go wrong?

(implication)

```
(¬p v q) ∧ (¬q ⇒  r)
```

(implication)

```
(¬p v q) ∧ (¬¬q v r)
```

(double negation)

```
(¬p v q) ∧ (q v r)
```

(commutativity)

```
(q v ¬p) ∧ (q v r)
```

(distributivity)

```
q v (¬p ∧ r)
```

(commutivity)

```
q v (r ∧ ¬p)
```

(commutativity)

```
(r ∧ ¬p) v q
```

(implication)

```
(r ∧ ¬p) ⇒ q
```

and then CompilerSaysNo pulls hair out?

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your last invocation of commutatitivity, you have

$$(r \land ¬p) \lor q$$

Then you invoked implication, but forgot to negate the $(r \land \lnot p)$. So everything up to and including the second-to-last line is fine!

Using the definition of implication:

$$(r\land \lnot p) \lor q \equiv \lnot(r \land \lnot p)\rightarrow q$$

Using DeMorgan's

$$\equiv (\lnot r \lor \lnot \lnot p) \rightarrow q$$

By double negation, that gives us:

$$\equiv (\lnot r \lor p) \rightarrow q$$

Using the definition of implication, that gives us

$$\equiv (r\rightarrow p) \rightarrow q$$  as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! You have

\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}(r\wedge \neg p)\vee q &\equiv (\neg\neg r\wedge\neg p)\vee q\\ &\equiv \neg(\neg r\vee p)\vee q\\ &\equiv (\neg r\vee p)\to q\\ &\equiv (r\to p)\to q\end{aligned}\end{equation*}